# env2 cannot find .env file

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I installed env2 via npm in my project. I created a config.env file in my root directory that contains the following:

```
DB_URL = mongodb://admin:user@password.mlab.com:41968/herokuerg_hc9xjmcl
```

I try to require it and use it in my node.js erver like this:

```
// Requiring the dependencies
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const itemRoutes = express.Router();
require('env2')('config.env');


app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());



mongoose.connect(DB_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true } )

const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open', function() {
  console.log('Connection to MongoDB established succesfully!');
});

// Serve static assets
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('build'));
}


itemRoutes.route('/').get( async (req, res) => {
  let collection = connection.collection("posts");
  let response = await collection.find({}).sort({date: -1})
  .toArray();
  res.send(response);
});


app.use('/', itemRoutes);


app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log('Server is running on' + ' ' + PORT);
})
```

But when I start the server file I get this error:

```
WARNING:  env2 was required to load an .env file:
```

For some strange reason env2 does not detect an .env file, why and how can I fix this? I tried reinstalling the node modules, even changing the file to a .env.json format and still it does not work.

Comment: you can use dotenv.

Comment: Remove .env from config require('env2')('config.env');

Answer (score 0):

Try dotenv npm.

```
npm install dotenv

require('dotenv').config()
```

.env file data

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=s1mpl3

const db = require('db')
db.connect({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS
})
```